# delete all cookies with specific string in name

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to delete some cookies in my application. They are all created in the application itself.

In my case, all cookies with a special string in it should be destroyed.

At the moment i have following code to unset a single cookie:

```
var expires = new Date();
expires.setTime(expires.getTime() - 100);
document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; expires=' + expires.toUTCString() + '; path=' + path + '; domain=' + domain;
```

my cookie names are all like this: cookiename_identifier
and all with cookiename_ should be deleted.

Comment: Can you give an example to what `document.cookie` (containing several values you want to get rid of) outputs?

Answer (score 3):

```
// Get an array of all cookie names (the regex matches what we don't want)
var cookieNames = document.cookie.split(/=[^;]*(?:;\s*|$)/);

// Remove any that match the pattern
for (var i = 0; i < cookieNames.length; i++) {
    if (/^cookiename_/.test(cookieNames[i])) {
        document.cookie = cookieNames[i] + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=' + path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
// Get an array of cookies
var arrSplit = document.cookie.split(";");

for(var i = 0; i < arrSplit.length; i++)
{
    var cookie = arrSplit[i].trim();
    var cookieName = cookie.split("=")[0];

    // If the prefix of the cookie's name matches the one specified, remove it
    if(cookieName.indexOf("cookiename_") === 0) {

        // Remove the cookie
        document.cookie = cookieName + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    document.cookie.split(";").forEach(function(cookie) {

        var cookieName = cookie.trim().split("=")[0];

        // If the prefix of the cookie's name matches the one specified, remove it
        if (cookieName.indexOf("cookiename_") === 0) {

            // Remove the cookie
            document.cookie = cookieName + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

This works perfectly for me.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    } else 
        var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}


function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

var cookieNames = document.cookie.split(/=[^;]*(?:;\s*|$)/);
for (var i = 0; i < cookieNames.length; i++) {
    if (cookieNames[i].includes(pattern)) {
        eraseCookie(cookieNames[i]);
    }
}
```

Functions `eraseCookie` and `createCookie` are taken from here https://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html. Hope this helps